# Factory design pattern location of switch statements

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I am trying to wrap my head around the usefulness of the factory design pattern.

Like many implementations of this design pattern (ie http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx) there is a switch statement in Main() that probes a string to decide which ConcreteComputerFactory to create (which is later sent to a ComputerAssembler.Assemble(ComputerFactory factory) method).

The way I see the problem: 
1. the user of the factory (Main()) "knows" the concrete factory implementations which by the very definition of the design pattern is supposed to be hidden from.
2. whenever a new concreteComputerFactory is introduced, the abstraction doesn't hold grounds! we have to go to the client (Main()) to add another if/case statement.

Proposition:
Move the if/switch statement/s to ComputerAssembler. (this has a slight problem that now ComputerAssembler has 2 reasons to change: a. overall stuff related to the creation b. adding a new ConcreteComputerFactory. but: this is certainly much better than in the client (Main))

I assume that I just don't fully grasp the idea yet. I would like to hear from you why the problems I specified are incorrect, and why my proposition isn't a better idea

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of the factory design pattern does not come at factory *creation* time, but when the factory and its products are *used*.  The code that creates the factory knows what concrete type it is creating.  It's only after the factory has been created, when the factory and its products are used via their base interfaces instead of their concrete types, that you see the benefit of the factory pattern.  Code which operates on the base interfaces can create and use any number of different concrete classes without changing any code.

For example:

```
main()
{
  // The point isn't to hide concrete types at factory creation time
  Factory* fact = new ConcreteFactoryA();
  f(fact);
}

void f(Factory* fact)
{
  // This is where the benefit of the factory pattern is found, 
  // where the factory is *used*, not where it is created
  Product* p = fact.CreateProduct();
  p.DoSomething();
  UseProduct(p);
}
```

If I replace ConcreteFactoryA with ConcreteFactoryB, the code which creates the factory has to know about that change.  But I *don't* have to change `f()` in any way.  That's where the benefit comes in.  Once I've created the factory, the rest of my code can accommodate different concrete types without any changes.

Comment: Based upon your input I get one conclusion: factory is another way of saying "program to the interface, not to the concrete implementation". I agree with this idea, as it would allow us to decouple from concrete implementations. but do we? I don't think so. because having even one(!) single method (main()) that IS coupled to specific implementation causes the coupling. I would prefer to move it out of that class, having another class deciding which specific implementation to use (based on some input it gets from main()) and then the coupling would be nil. would this be better or worse? thanks

Comment: Yep, you got it.  What makes the factory pattern different from simply "program to the interface" is that it also consolidates many separate creation decisions (which concrete P1 should I create here?, which concrete P2 should I create there?) into one decision up front (which concrete factory should I create?).  Somewhere, some code has to know what concrete factory it is creating, and/or know how to choose from among whatever concrete factories are available.  But once you've made that decision, you don't have to re-explore that decision every time you need to create a new object.

Comment: As for decoupling from main(), you can move the logic for concrete factory selection and creation wherever you want.  You can also use reflection to further decouple things if your language supports it.  My current project does exactly this - look for DLLs in a particular folder, ask each DLL if it has any implementations of the factory interface.

Answer (score 0):

`ComputerAssembler` is responsible for assembling the computer :) Mixing of responsibilities is always a bad idea. Usually factory is shared by several independent classes, e.g. `ComputerAssembler`, `ComputerWarehouse`. That's why correct implementation is chosen separately at the very beginning.

Construction and choosing of the right factory is not a part of this pattern, it is a separate problem. Having a if/else statements in Main is not good also, logic of choosing the factory and providing it to the other object should be handled separately. How? It depends on the logic of your application. Here are a couple of examples:

1) The right implementation is configured per application start, then you just need to set the right implementation in your configuration file. It can be done by **Inversion of Control** framework, here is short example with usage of Spring:

```
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/my-context.xml");
    ComputerFactory computerFactory = applicationContext.getBean(ComputerFactory.class);
    new ComputerBuilder().build(computerFactory);
```

2) Your app should be able to switch the factory on Runtime. More complex logic here, you can create one more class responsible for making the choice and pass it to `ComputerBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but you have answered an other question than the one I was asking. The fact that my proposition is not good in the regards of mixing responsibilities I already know, as I have written in my question. but the question of why is it OK to stay in the client (Main) is the more interesting one. In addition, there will be no ComputerWarehouse. the whole point of ComputerAssembler being abstracted from both the concrete factory, and concrete object is so there will be no need to create more of its type. And the IoC container requires clarification if it still have relevence

Answer (score 0):

for choosing the implementor of the abstract factory, you need Selector class too.

Selector has the method

```
Factory select() {

return new ConcreteFactory();

}
```

and the client ( main() ) will use this method.

after this. if you have to choose another implementor, you will change the select method